# How to render different maps (diffuse, depth, specular, shaded) of a 3d model from different camera angles, in Blender?

Tags: computer-vision, rendering, blender, texture-mapping, render-to-texture

My task is to render a 3d model from different camera angles. Along with the original snapshot, my script should also render depth/normal/albedo/diffuse/mask/specular maps of the object in view.
I already have a script for rendering depth/normal/albedo maps. https://github.com/panmari/stanford-shapenet-renderer
How can I render diffuse/mask/specular maps as well.
The online tutorials on generating these maps follow the technique of converting one map to another(like diffuse to specular), rather than rendering a 3d model from different angles.

Answer (score 0):

I have been also trying to get something similar. So far my approach is manual. This process is easy enough to be converted into python code quickly. I have tested only EEVEE with this.

The process is basically enabling holdout for each object or object groups that need to be segmented in different view layers. Then after rendering outputting the `Alpha` from `Render Layers` node within compositing tab with desired view layer selected. They can be output with `File Output` node in `BW` or `RGB`.

[image]

[image]

Similarly in `view layer properties` tab there is option for diffuse and specular passes. After rendering once with these selected the the output will be available in `Render Layers` node.

I have described the entire [process here](https://github.com/quickgrid/AI-Resources/blob/master/code-lab/blender/README.md) in detail. There is also an existing GitHub python repo named [bpycv](https://github.com/DIYer22/bpycv) that generates various types of masks and also generates depth map.

#### References

- https://github.com/quickgrid/AI-Resources/tree/master/code-lab/blender
- https://github.com/DIYer22/bpycv